# How to fix slow update query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I'm using the following query to populate a table 
of daily temperature extremes from a large set of readings. There are 33 thermometers, and readings are taken every minute; thus, there are about 46K readings (i.e. rows) per day. But only 33 rows get added to `extremes` each day.

Originally I had imagined to run this query each time a new reading was inserted, in order to keep today's extremes up to date. However, I soon discovered this query takes a LONG time to run: on my MacBook 5½ minutes on a full day's readings.

I'd be very interested in some insight into why it's so slow, and perhaps how to make this query faster, or a better alternative. Note `extremes` has both `Sensor_ID` and `Date` as primary keys, since that's what's unique about each row.

**THANKS !!**

```
insert into extremes(Date, Sensor_ID, `min`, `max`, `avg`)
    select date(DateTime) as `Date`, Sensor_ID as Sensor_ID,
        min(Value) as `min`, max(Value) as `max`, avg(Value) as `avg`
        from readings where date(`DateTime`) = date(NOW())
    group by date(DateTime), Sensor_ID
on duplicate key update 
    `min` = values(`min`), `max` = values(`max`), `avg` = values(`avg`);
```

As requested, here are the tables

```
CREATE TABLE `readings` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Sensor_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `DateTime` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Value` double NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_idx` (`Sensor_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `ID` FOREIGN KEY (`Sensor_ID`) REFERENCES `sensors` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=54500039 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci

CREATE TABLE `extremes` (
  `Date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `Sensor_ID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `min` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `max` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `updates` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Date`,`Sensor_ID`),
  KEY `ID_idx` (`Sensor_ID`),
  CONSTRAINT `foo` FOREIGN KEY (`Sensor_ID`) REFERENCES `sensors` (`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Are your source tables indexed? Also, it appears that you're calling NOW() a lot. Wouldn't it be better to compute the date you're checking for prior to doing the select?

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Add `explain extended` to the front of your query. That will show you what's going on with regards to the index and so on. You can identify bottlenecks this way.

Comment: This query can't use an index on your `DateTime` column even if you've got such an index, because you've put `DateTime` inside a function call. So it's going to scan the whole table, however millions of rows you have, to find those that are for the current date.

Comment: When you ask for help with query optimization, always include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`, so we don't have to guess what indexes and data types your table currently has.

Comment: @BillKarwin 40 million rows in the readings table. I'll take DateTime out of the date( ) call and see what happens.

Comment: @BillKarwin changed to where `DateTime` >= date(date_add(NOW(), interval -1 day)) and `DateTime` < date(NOW()) and it's now 25sec. Wow!

Comment: @JamesMcPherson Indexing was indeed the answer, along with getting DateTime out of the function call. BTW I tried with a literal date and it didn't seem to help, but the effect was probably in the noise compared to accidentally searching 40 million rows, as Bill Karwin pointed out.

Comment: I'm glad we were able to help! You might like my presentation [How to Design Indexes, Really](https://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/how-to-design-indexes-really), and a video of me presenting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELR7-RdU9XU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an index to the `DateTime` column in your `readings` table.

Then try the below SQL:

```
insert into extremes(Date, Sensor_ID, `min`, `max`, `avg`)
    select date(DateTime) as `Date`, Sensor_ID as Sensor_ID,
        min(Value) as `min`, max(Value) as `max`, avg(Value) as `avg`
        from readings where `DateTime` >= date_format(curdate(), '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')
    group by date(DateTime), Sensor_ID
on duplicate key update 
    `min` = values(`min`), `max` = values(`max`), `avg` = values(`avg`);
```

Comment: Even without an index taking DateTime out of the date() function gets this query down to 25sec from 5½ minutes!!

Comment: Is it faster with the index on the `DateTime` column?

Comment: Oh, just a little… 200x faster. With index, and DateTime out of the function call, it's now less than 200ms. Double wow!

Answer (score 1):

```
UNIQUE KEY `ID_UNIQUE` (`ID`),
```

slows down modifications to `readings`.  It is *redundant* since the `PRIMARY KEY *is* a unique key.  Drop it.

Do the IODKU only on the one row you are inserting, not all the rows:

```
insert into extremes(Date, Sensor_ID, `min`, `max`)
    VALUES(... , ..., ..., ...)   -- Place constants here (from the sensor)
on duplicate key update 
    `min` = LEAST(`min`, values(`min`)),
    `max` = GREATEST(`max`, values(`max`);
```

Then have a nightly job to set the avg.

That way, you are touching 1 row, not up to 1440.

Another technique is to gather the readings for a minute, then apply them in a single query.

Do you have millions of sensors?  Rethink the use of a 4-byte `INT` for `Sensor_ID`; there are smaller integers.

Where'd you find those sensors?  I doubt if you need more than the 7 significant digits of `FLOAT` (4 bytes) instead of the 8-byte `DOUBLEs`.

My point about the data types is -- shrinking the data will also speed things up, especially if you get to the point of having too much data to cache in RAM.

Phrasing: "both Sensor_ID and Date as primary keys" implies that there are two different PKs, which is impossible.  Instead "Sensor_ID and Date form a composite primary key".  And, yes, that is what you need for that table.  Whether you put `Date` first or last depends on what your typical `SELECT` is.

`FOREIGN KEYs` are another cost.  Each time an insert is done, the other table needs to be checked to verify the existing of the id.  By now you have debugged your code sufficiently; FKs are arguably a waste.

The `avg` *could* be computed every minute, but (1) it is somewhat meaningless until the day is over, and (2) it would require and extra column (with the count).